# change default font color in html create NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

"123" and "789" default color is black but I want to change to another color,how can i do for this ?

```
TTTAttributedLabel * cmdTextView = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 100, 100, 30)];
cmdTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
cmdTextView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:cmdTextView];

NSString *s = @"123<font color='#FFFFFF'>456</font>789" ;
NSMutableAttributedString *attribute = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithData:[s dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
[cmdTextView setText:attribute];
```

Comment: Enumerate the attributes, and set the color wanted when it's the case.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution. Hope can help u

```
NSString *s1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:"<span style=\"color:Your color\">%@</span>", s];
```